# Monitor MongoDb with Prometheus and Grafana

Tags: mongodb, grafana, prometheus

I have tried to monitor mongo db with Prometheus and Grafana

```
 wget https://github.com/dcu/mongodb_exporter/releases/download/v1.0.0/mongodb_exporter-linux-amd64
chmod 777 mongodb_exporter-linux-amd64
./mongodb_exporter-linux-amd64 &
```

it starts running in 9001 port;

Checked in Prometheus :
 state shows as UP for this server:9001
metrics were listed in the promethus

but it reporting the following in the  server

```
E1010 02:39:18.767155   26635 replset_status.go:232] Failed to get replSet status.
E1010 02:39:18.767293   26635 oplog_status.go:127] Failed to get local.oplog_rs collection stats.
```

And how to get these data in Grafana UI dashboards

Comment: Does mongo have a node exporter by default?  Did you use anything that exposes this info from mongo?

Answer (score 0):

Two things you need to make sure to monitor mongodb using prometheus.

1. Add all the servers in you replica set using the comma separated values.
2. User provided should have the admin privileges to get all the replica status.

   `-mongodb.uri=mongodb://<user>:<password>@mongodb-1:27017,mongodb-2:27017,mongodb-3:27017&authSource=admin`

   `-mongodb.username=<user>`